# Ubuntu apt-get cannot find any versions of gcc and g++

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gcc

I was trying to compile some C++ programs on my Ubuntu virtual machine, it need g++ version 4.9 and higher. But I find the g++ on this machine only has version 4.6.3, so I tried to update g++ and gcc with this command:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc='4.9' g++='4.9'
```

and it returned:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Version '4.9' for 'gcc' was not found
E: Version '4.9' for 'g++' was not found
```

Curiously, I tried another version 4.6, and it also returned the same words.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Version '4.6' for 'gcc' was not found
E: Version '4.6' for 'g++' was not found
```

What happened with my machine?

Comment: Download the src of gcc on gcc.gnu.org, and build it.

Comment: That's the wrong syntax. You are trying to install version XX of some meta-package that just provides a couple symlinks, you should try to install package gcc-4.9 instead (not saying it will be available). Did you try upgrading the whole system to a newer ubuntu version? Note that there is a specific site askubuntu instead of stackoverflow (same network).

Comment: I think you need to change the equal sign (`=`) to a dash (`-`) in the package name. Also drop the quote. Use `gcc-4.9` and `g++-4.9` instead of `g++='4.9'`. On Fedora, I believe you use `gcc-c++`.

Comment: I tried the syntax like 'gcc-4.9', But it returns the same.

Answer (score 1):

You need to point to an older Ubuntu release.

They have it [as seen here for gcc-4.9](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=gcc-4.9) and [here for gcc-4.6](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=gcc-4.6).